# Internal server error 500 when postig data to laravel project using Axios in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I am trying to send data to my laravel application using axios in Vue but i had this error

```
Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at e.exports (axios.min.js:8)
    at e.exports (axios.min.js:8)
    at XMLHttpRequest.l.(anonymous function) (http://localhost:8000/js/axios.min.js:8:3282)
```

Axios code:

```
   addExperience: function () {
                axios.post(window.Laravel.url + '/addexperience', this.experience)
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response.data)
                    if(response.data.etat){
                            this.open = false;
                            this.experiences.push(this.experience);
                }})
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    console.log(window.Laravel.url + '/addexperience');
                    console.log(this.experience.titre);
                    console.log(this.experience);
                });
            }
        },
```

Route:

```
    Route::post('/addexperience', 'CvController@addExperience');
```

Controller:

```
    public function addExperience(Request $request){
    $exp = new Experience();
    $exp->titre = $request->titre;
    $exp->description = $request->description;
    $exp->debut = $request->debut;
    $exp->fin = $request->fin;
    $exp->cv_id = $request->cv_id;
    $exp->save();

    return Response()->json(['etat' => true, 'id' =>$exp->id]);
}
```

Please help me

Comment: since `500` is a server error, check the server's logs/errors.

Comment: Check your network tab to see the actual error. It could be a million things

Comment: You just copied the message from your browser's console which is not the server log. Check in your console where you start the laravel server.

Comment: Or you can set APP_DEBUG=true in the .env file so that you can see the full error stacktrace in the AJAX call using Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug

Comment: the app_debug is true and the apache error log file doesnt contain errors i cant find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error `500` often means something in the back-end went wrong, so you can check go to the console of your browser > network and check there the error that laravel threw, without that info we can only guess. so let's guess

Since we don't know what laravel version you're using i will asume you're using 5.x

```
 public function addExperience(Request $request){
        $exp = new Experience(); //Maybe this model wasnt injected, do use App\Experience; to do so
        //(Generally models are added in the app directory, if yours is in a subforlder just add it to the path, use App\folder\Experience);
        $exp->titre = $request->titre;
        $exp->description = $request->description;
        $exp->debut = $request->debut;
        $exp->fin = $request->fin;
        $exp->cv_id = $request->cv_id;
        $exp->save();

        return Response()->json(['etat' => true, 'id' =>$exp->id]);
        //if youre using the response helper it should be in lowercase "response()" if you're using the facade you must import the dependency with use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
```

Comment: Thanx Carlos .Experience Model is already injected .I tried all your suggestion but no result :/

Comment: could you right click on the browser > inspect element > go to network tab  then do the ajax again and check the network call with the 500 error , click it and in the response tab you should see that the problem is

Comment: Thank you very much Carlos . I followed ur advice .It was a missed DB column (user_id) that i forgot to declare it